# Xamarin Forms Button Command doesn't fire after adding button effect

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a button like this:

```
<Button Margin="0,20,0,0" Command="{Binding OnSkip}" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Primary}" CornerRadius="2"
      Text="Terms and Conditions of Use" VerticalOptions="End" TextColor="White">
  <Button.Effects>
      <effects1:ButtonClickEffect></effects1:ButtonClickEffect>
  </Button.Effects>
</Button>
```

Upon adding the button effect inside the button, the 'OnSkip' command no longer fires and I'm not sure why.

The button click effect code is implemented as follows:

```
public class AndroidButtonClickEffect : PlatformEffect
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        this.Control.Touch += this.Control_Touch;
    }

    private void Control_Touch(object sender, Android.Views.View.TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Event.Action == MotionEventActions.Down)
        {
            this.SetColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Blue);
        }
        else if (e.Event.Action == MotionEventActions.Up)
        {
            this.SetColor(Android.Graphics.Color.LightBlue);
        }
    }

    private void SetColor(Android.Graphics.Color color)
    {
        this.Control.SetBackgroundColor(color);
    }

    protected override void OnDetached()
    {
        this.Control.Touch -= this.Control_Touch;
    }
}
```

Removing the button effect causes the command to fire again. Why does the button effect interfere with the command firing? Is there a way I can get the effect to invoke the desired command (generically so I can reuse the effect)?

Thanks.

Comment: Cheers to the guy that posted the link - it helped me solve the problem: https://alexdunn.org/2017/12/27/xamarin-tip-xamarin-forms-long-press-effect/ 
Not sure why the answer was deleted. It contained only a link, but it was still useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the main project, I added the following class, which binds the Command:

```
public class ButtonClickEffect : RoutingEffect
{
    public ButtonClickEffect() : base("Framework.ButtonClickEffect") { }

    public static readonly BindableProperty CommandProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("Command", typeof(ICommand), typeof(ButtonClickEffect));

    public static ICommand GetCommand(BindableObject view)
    {
        return (ICommand)view.GetValue(CommandProperty);
    }

    public static void SetCommand(BindableObject view, ICommand value)
    {
        view.SetValue(CommandProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty CommandParameterProperty =
        BindableProperty.CreateAttached("CommandParameter", typeof(object),
            typeof(ButtonClickEffect), (object)null);

    public static object GetCommandParameter(BindableObject view)
    {
        return view.GetValue(CommandParameterProperty);
    }

    public static void SetCommandParameter(BindableObject view, object value)
    {
        view.SetValue(CommandParameterProperty, value);
    }
}
```

The Android implementation was implemented as follows:

```
[assembly:ResolutionGroupName("Framework")]
[assembly:ExportEffect(typeof(AndroidButtonClickEffect), "ButtonClickEffect")]
namespace Framework.Droid.Effects
{
    public class AndroidButtonClickEffect : PlatformEffect
    {
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            Control.Touch += Control_Touch;
        }

        private void Control_Touch(object sender, Android.Views.View.TouchEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Event.Action == MotionEventActions.Down)
            {
                SetColor(Color.LightBlue);
            }
            else if (e.Event.Action == MotionEventActions.Up)
            {
                SetColor(Color.Blue);
            }

            var command = ButtonClickEffect.GetCommand(Element);
            command?.Execute(ButtonClickEffect.GetCommandParameter(Element));
        }

        private void SetColor(Color color)
        {
            Control.SetBackgroundColor(color);
        }

        protected override void OnDetached()
        {
            Control.Touch -= Control_Touch;
        }
    }
}
```

I then removed the 'Command' property from my button and replaced it as follows:

```
<Button Margin="0,20,0,0" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Primary}" CornerRadius="2"
      Text="Terms and Conditions of Use" VerticalOptions="End" TextColor="White" 
      effects1:ButtonClickEffect.Command="{Binding OnSkip}" effects1:ButtonClickEffect.CommandParameter="{Binding .}">
  <Button.Effects>
      <effects1:ButtonClickEffect></effects1:ButtonClickEffect>
  </Button.Effects>
</Button>
```

In all honesty, the command binding is a lot more awkward now (all this code just to get a simple button effect), but the important thing is that it now works. Now I need to work out how implement for iOS.

Credit from [here](https://alexdunn.org/2017/12/27/xamarin-tip-xamarin-forms-long-press-effect/) for the answer and whoever posted this URL as an answer (it got deleted).